# Does the break statement break out of loops or only out of if statements?

Tags: java, break

In the following code, does the `break` statement break out of the `if` statement only or out of the `for` loop too?

I need it to break out of the loop too.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (i == temp)
        // do something
    else {
        temp = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That would break out of the for loop. In fact `break` only makes sense when talking about `loops`, since they break from the `loop` entirely, while `continue` only goes to the next `iteration`.

Answer (score 15):

An unlabelled `break` only breaks out of the enclosing `switch`, `for`, `while` or `do-while` construct.  It does not take `if` statements into account.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html for more details.

Answer (score 8):

It also goes out of the loop.

You can also use labeled breaks that can break out of outer loops (and arbitrary code blocks).

```
looplbl: for(int i=;i<;i++){

    if (i == temp)
        // do something
    else {
        temp = i;
        break looplbl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It breaks the loop, but why not explicitly put the condition in the for itself? It would be more readable and you would not have to write the if statement at all

(if i==temp then temp = i is totally pointless)

Answer (score 2):

`break` is to break out of any loop.

Answer (score 2):

It will break out of the loop always.

Answer (score 2):

Break never refers to if/else statements. It only refers to loops (if/while) and switch statements.

Answer (score 0):

Generally `break` statement breaks out of loops (`for`, `while`, and `do...while`) and `switch` statements.

In Java there are 2 variant of `break`.

### 1. `Labeled break`

It break outs of the outer loop where you put the lable.

```
breakThis: for(...){
   for(...){
      ... 
      break breakThis;  // breaks the outer for loop
   }
}
```

### 2. `Unlabeled break`

It is the statement you used in your question.

It breaks the loop in which it is written. Generally inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

It would break you out of the for loop. Generally **break** statement is used to optimise the running time of your program. Means when the given condition is met, use **break** statement so that it will take you out of the loop and ignores the remaining iterations.

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer, please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions. You'd comment instead.