# How to break out of multiple if blocks inside while loop in java?

Tags: java, loops, coding-style, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I wanted to break out of each if condition and make a validation for i,
Currently, what is happing is after all the if condition is verified only the only loop is getting considered, is there any logic to make the code validate after each if condition, The simple soltion is to add the (i<=10) in each of the if condition. is there any other alternative?

```
code sample below
    while(i<=10){
      if(condition1){
          //action1
        }
      if(condition2){
          //action2
        }
      if(condition3){
          //action3
        }
      if(condition4){
          //action4
        }
      }
```

Comment: You need to break out of `if` sorry i am not getting it

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear.  Please add some actual example actions and explain what you want to have happen.

Comment: If you are confused about the `break` statement then you should check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47476792/8587776). also please add more details in your post.

Comment: Once the condition1 is verified then flow or focus comes to condition2 then to condition3 etc. The way i wanted is Once the first condition is satisfied and completed i need the control to go back to the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<outerloop_name>:
while(i<=10){
      if(condition1){
          //action1
          break <outerloop_name>;
        }
      if(condition2){
          //action2
          break <outerloop_name>;
        }
      if(condition3){
          //action3
          break <outerloop_name>;
        }
      if(condition4){
          //action4
          break <outerloop_name>;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make a boolean thats 'true' when it loops and false when it finds the condition...

```
boolean looping = true;
while (i<=10 && looping)
{
      if(condition1){
          //action1
          looping = false;
        }
      if(condition2){
          //action1
          looping = false;
        }
      if(condition3){
          //action1
          looping = false;
        }
      if(condition4){
          //action1
          looping = false;
        }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to veriy the condition again for the while loop, got the answer from other reference thanks @marc.